# Set Select list default value based on URL query

Tags: php, html

I have the following that gives me a "Jump" menu to put a query in the current URL like ?date=2016-07

```
<?php
    $date = explode('-', $_GET['date']);
    $year = $date[0];
    $month = $date[1];
?>

<form>
<select name="date" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 18; ++$i) {
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
    $value = date('Y-m', $time);
    $label = date('F Y', $time);
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);
  }
  ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Once the page has jumped, I want to display the new date as the default value. I thought you did this by giving a "value" attribute to the select list, but that didnt work. Reading up on this further, you need to add "selected" to one of the options.

How would I add "selected" to one of the options if it matches the date query in the URL?

Comment: test is `$_GET['date'] == $value` and if it is add `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
    $date = explode('-', $_GET['date']);
    $year = $date[0];
    $month = $date[1];
?>

<form>
<select name="date" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 18; ++$i) {
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
    $value = date('Y-m', $time);
    $label = date('F Y', $time);
    if(strcmp($value,$_GET['date']) == 0)
       //If 0, $value and $_GET['date'] are the same: The option is selected
       printf('<option value="%s" selected>%s</option>', $value, $label);
    else
       printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);
  }
  ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$selected = ($value == $_GET['date']) ?  'selected' : '';
printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $value, $selected, $label);
```